# How to fix the bug related to scroll bounce effect on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, responsive-design

So this error is related to scroll effect.

As I open my website (https://bobobee.com) on a mobile browser and scroll down, it often gets stuck and bounce back.

This started happening after I enabled Auto Adsense Ads on the site. I am not able to figure what exactly is causing this error and how to fix this bug.

Comment: Work fine to me

Comment: Did you wait until the page loaded completely? Try scrolling down while it is still loading

Comment: It's working but some time it gets stuck . But didn't bounce back.

Comment: How can I fix this?